# How to get all fields in VF page using custom controller?

Tags: visualforce, controller

This is my Controller:

```
public class exportContactRecords
{
    public List <Contact> contactList { get; set; }   
    String query;   
    String allFields = '';
    public exportContactRecords()
    {
        String objectName = 'Contact';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName ).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        set<string> mapset = fieldMap.keyset(); 
        contactList = NEW List <Contact> (); 

        for ( String str:mapset )
        {

            allFields += str +', '; 

        }
        allFields = allFields.removeEnd(', ');

        query = 'SELECT '+ allFields + ' FROM '  + objectName;

        System.debug('----------'+query);   

        contactList = Database.query(query);
        System.debug('----------'+contactList);
    }
}
```

Here I am getting all the fields through this dynamic query

This is my VF page:

```
<apex:page Controller="exportContactRecords" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" >
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="c">
               <apex:column value="{!c.LastName}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Here I have taken only 1 field LastName but I want to have all the contact fields in that excel sheet.Please give me solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render the `<apex:column>` dynamically based on the number of fields queried, you should have a tap on number of fields queried in a list of string. Then use that list of fields to get the values from your list using `<apex:repeat>`

```
public class exportContactRecords
{
    public List <Contact> contactList { get; set; }   
    String query;   
    String allFields = '';
    public exportContactRecords()
    {
        String objectName = 'Contact';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaMap.get(objectName ).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        set<string> mapset = fieldMap.keyset(); 
        contactList = NEW List <Contact> (); 
        **List<String> lstFields = new List<String>();**
        for ( String str:mapset )
        {

            allFields += str +', '; 
            **lstFields.add(str);**

        }
        allFields = allFields.removeEnd(', ');

        query = 'SELECT '+ allFields + ' FROM '  + objectName;

        System.debug('----------'+query);   

        contactList = Database.query(query);
        System.debug('----------'+contactList);
    }
}
```

Here I am getting all the fields through this dynamic query

This is my VF page:

```
<apex:page Controller="exportContactRecords" ContentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" >
  <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="c">
        **<apex:repeat value="{!lstFields}" var="FieldLable">  
            <apex:column value="{!c[FieldLable]}"/>  
        </apex:repeat>**                   
     </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Refer [Page Block Table With Dynamic Columns In Salesforce](http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2012/11/page-block-table-with-dynamic-columns.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dynamic Visualforce components as explained here [Dynamic Visualforce components documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Dynamic_Visualforce_Components)

Basically you define a Dynamic Visualforce component on your VF page. Like this:

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!thePanel}"/>
```

And then using apex you can add your fields to that panel.

```
Component.Apex.InputField inTxt = new Component.Apex.InputField(value=rec.name);
inTxt.expressions.value = "{!rec.name}";
```

I see you already use Describe to determine which fields to put. You can make use of that to dynamically add fields to your Panel.

Answer (score 1):

You will use [Dynamic Field Bindings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf.htm) Concept here

You are almost there with controller code but you may need one more list with all fields .

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Custom Object Fields and Data" id="fields">    
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Dynamic Object">  
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="c">
  <apex:repeat value="{!listObjectFields}" var="fieldAPIName">  
    <apex:outputField value="{!c[fieldAPIName]}"/> 
  </apex:repeat>
  </apex:pageblocktable/>  
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The controller code

```
 public list<Contact> contactList {get;set;}  
 public List<String> listObjectFields {get;set;}
```